# Placeholder color of textarea

Tags: html, css

I have a text-area like below.

```css
textarea::placeholder {
  color: #999 !important;
}

textarea::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999 !important;
}

input[type='text']::placeholder, textarea::placeholder{
    color:#999 !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Check List" name="check_list" /><br/>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Description" name="description"></textarea>
```

I am getting output like below

[image]

I am applying same color for both `Check List` and `Description` field. But out put is not same. Why the output is not same ?

[image]

My `Check List` CSS is like below

```
input[type='text']::placeholder, textarea::placeholder{
    color:#999 !important;
}
```

Comment: Please add the checklist to the snippet I made you

Comment: Could it possibly be because of the !important on the first one?

Comment: Thanks for reply @mplungjan. I used `.form-control::placeholder {
    color: #999 !important;
}` css for  `Check List`. Thanks

Comment: Add the HTML and CSS for the "Check list" element to your question so that we can see both together.

Comment: If you solved it feel free to delete. It is not useful for other people than you

Comment: @mplungjan, how to delete a question ? I tried to delete question before but SO is not allowed to delete question.

Comment: Next to edit there should be a delete. If not, please change the SNIPPET to include ALL RELEVANT details instead of spreading them around the text. I updated the snippet with CSS, but is it in the same order as you have it in real life? Click "edit above snippet" to change the code

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the styles to a `<textarea/>` element, but the checklist element is `<input type='text'/>`. You need to apply the css styles to `input[type='text']`, or whatever selector you want.